# Why FREAD give error on Linux but not on Windows?

Tags: c, linux, fread, segmentation-fault

I have a code that suddenly started to have a strange behavior. It was working fine like 3 months ago, I left it aside for working on other projects and this week I returned to it. To my surprise when I ran the code the results were strange.

The code is supposed to read a bin file that simulates a underground earth velocity model, shooting an acoustic pulse that propagates through it, then record the seismogram generated plus the front waves. Every 400 iterations  all saved as bin files that I can open using another application.

When I ran the code this week the image files generated were no longer horizontal, it was inclined like 45 degrees. I had a suspicion it was something related to some update in Windows 7 or CodeBlocks. So I decided to use Linux. I installed Oracle Linux on my laptop, an old Dual core Pentium with 8Gb RAM, making it a dual boot. Installed Netbeans 8, got the code, did some small modifications and ran it. To my surprise it gives segmentation fault on the first `fread` command which it was not happening on Windows.

Why this different behaviour? Is it possible to be related to the IDE, or the environment?

Piece of the code giving problems:

```
    vel = (double **) malloc (Nz * sizeof(double *));
      for (i = 0; i < Nz; i++)
    vel[i] = (double *) malloc (Nx * sizeof(double));
    modelo = (char *) malloc (256 * sizeof(char));
    modelo == "vp_model_400x300.bin";
    //reading velocity grid
    printf("\nSaving velocity model...\n");
    vel_arq = fopen(modelo, "rb");
    for (j = 0; j < Nx; j++)
    for (i = 0; i < Nz; i++)
    {
      fread (&v, sizeof(float), 1, vel_arq);
      vel[i][j] = (double) v;
    }
    fclose(vel_arq);
```

The velocity model is a 400x300 bin file.

I'm already using `#include string.h`

Comment: This is a no-op: `modelo == "vp_model_400x300.bin";` It merely compares the pointer on the left (recently allocated memory) to the address of the first element of the array on the right and discard the result of the comparison.

Comment: Where is "v" allocated / defined?

Comment: @APC is it supposed to be a joke?? Well, as said the code works in windows, just the results are different, If I haven´t touched it, something on the system changed. Most likely some update or software that i installed modified the way it generates the bin files I believe. the thing is that i installed/uninstalled heaps of thigs these last three months, plus there were lots of Windows updates. What should i do ? Get back to a restore point from 3 months ago? The fact that I installed Oracle Linux is because i´m studying Oracle database too.

Comment: After `vel_arq = fopen(modelo, "rb");` is executed, what does NetBeans say the value of `vel_arc` is? It's probably 0 or NULL because `modelo` doesn't point to a valid file name. It's a good idea to check the return value of any function that can return a special value indicating failure.

Comment: @APC it is ok, no worries. Using Oracle Linux, that is pretty much like Redhat, but not as user friendly as Ubuntu, was a demand from the instructor. I´m not a professional programmer, only a student learning a lot of things at the same time. I just really want to become proficient in C++, but I´m still far away from it, I´m learning C++ by myself. That is why I have so many doubts about it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I´ll run the debugger again to check this value, thanks for the tip.